# Storing user contacts on server database (parse.com)

Tags: database, mobile, database-design, parse-platform, relational-database

My question is about database design.

I am storing user contacts on server(Parse.com) by making a class named the phone number(example. +917534310478) & within that 1 column of names & 1 column of its corresponding phone number.(*This method will not work because in parse.com class name does not  begin with + or a number, so I am making the class name as India7640985766*)

By using this style I will have millions of classes if I have millions of downloads.

I think this is not a good type of design concept.

I have studied about foreign key/ primary key in RDBMS, etc.

As I do not have much experience so I am really confused about designing this type of database.

Basically I am making a functionality similar to truecaller in my app.

Any help is appreciated about the database design,

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your class be named something like `Contact` and have key value pairs like: 'Phone', '+917534310478'?

Comment: Isn't +917534310478 the phone number?  Why would you need to store the phone number of an object with a key of the phone number?  Shouldn't the contact have a key of some contact ID and its attributes include phone numbers?  See Vintesh's answer; it makes sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you , could u please explain me in brief ?

Comment: My point is that there is no reason to have an object that stores a piece of information if the key to that object is the information that you want to retrieve.  How do you retrieve the object without already knowing its key?

Comment: Is your application supposed do verification via phone number? If so comment here and ill give an answer fit for you :) @VivekWarde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse have class named **USER(_USER)** - You have to use this only if want to use default **Login/SignUp** functionality of Parse.

Better you store your each *Contact Number* as UserName in USER class.

For managing list of friends you can specify column of type Array & store all friends'(which will ObjectIDs from USER class only.) **ObjectId(s)** as elements of that Array.

So whenever you need to fetch friends of any Contact then you can query them by their **ObjectId.** For CountryCode better you manage another Column with *String* datatype.

Comment: In Parse where can I find class named USER(_USER) ?

Comment: Can you explain me more clearly as I am new to parse.com about ObjectId(s)

Comment: To add USER class - Go to Dashboard & click on "Add Class" then choose User from Combo box. ObjectId is unique key for each object which is stored.

Comment: It does not need username & password, ! When My app will be complete, I will buy an sms gateway to verify the users phone number, Can it be done, If so then how to make it happen?

Comment: You can set verification code as password i.e. at sign up generate random verification code and set it as password & when verified change the password.

Comment: in Parse dashboard How can I specify column of type Array for storing list of friends, Do you mean to say the column containing the name of friends is type Array, & the column containing the phone numbers is type array ?

Comment: And whenever I need to fetch a friend of any contact then how can I query them by their ObjectId, ObjectId is only the random string, rather I can query by phone number or by name also ?

Comment: To find any object's ObjectId - Use `find` or `get` method - [REF](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving) & use column named _friends_ in USER class with type _Array_ and push object id of friends into that Array.